# Adding API_KEY from .env

Tags: reactjs, key, api-key, .env

I would like to import my api key that is saved in .env file like `API_KEY = my-key-goes-here`, to another js file and save it in variable const key, but when I try I get error 401, can anybody help please?

I expected to import api key from  .env file to another js file like this: `const key = process.env.API_KEY` and it didn't work, I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have this but you need require('dotenv').config() or for ES6 import 'dotenv/config' in your file.

Also have you tried to log the key to the console to make sure it is/isn't there?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#%EF%B8%8F-usage

Comment: Thank you, I had to install `path-browserify, os-browserify, stream-browserify, buffer, crypto-browserify`, and replace `API_KEY` with `REACT_APP_API_KEY`, it works now.